# Similar question suggestion list overwrite issue

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, user-interface, similar-questions

When posting a new question in StackOverflow, it shows similar questions. As one keeps on writing, list changes but they overlap with one another. This happens when you scroll down a bit when the new list is visible. Below is the screenshot for the same.

Web browser: `Mozilla`
Version: `77.0.1` 
Operating System: `Windows 10`

[image: Screenshot]